# Keep getting "undefined" however I try to parse a geojson file with javascript

Tags: javascript, geojson, getelementbyid

I have this geojson file:

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "Adresse":"### St-Roch",
            "Type":"famille"
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -73.6291292309761,
               45.52982413033413
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "Adresse":"### St-Roch",
            "Type":"organisme"
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -73.62943768501282,
               45.531770729329985
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This is (part of) my script:

```
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "photoParcEx.geojson", false);
        request.send(null);
        var dataJSON = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log(dataJSON.features.properties.Adresse);
        
        photoParcEx.addTo(maCarte).on('click', function () {
            sidebar.toggle();
            document.getElementById("sidebar").innerHTML = "Type : " + dataJSON.Adresse;
        });
```

I'm trying to send the "Adresse" key to an inner HTML but keep getting undefined. Same thing when I try to print the value with the console log.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: features is array, you can access it with index, example dataJSON.features[0].properties.Adresse

Comment: Didn't realize it was an array. The problem is that I want to access keys depending on the point that is chosen.

Comment: not sure what you mean by point, if you mean coordinates, you can try something like this var find = dataJSON.features.find(i => i.geometry.coordinates.indexOf(-73.62943768501282) > -1 && i.geometry.coordinates.indexOf(45.531770729329985) > -1);
console.log(find ? find.properties.Adresse : "not found");

Comment: Yeah sorry I wasn't clear. I meant every geojson object. Each object is projected on a map. I want, when I click one marker to send its keys to an inner HTML.

Comment: Can you share more of your script? What's `photoParcEx` and what JS lib are you using to render the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
photoParcEx.on('click', function (e) {
      sidebar.show();
            console.log(e.layer.feature.properties.Type);
            var photoDesc = document.getElementById("photoDesc");
            //$("sidebar").innerHTML = "Type : " + e.layer.properties.Type;
            if (photoDesc.style.display === 'none') {
                photoDesc.style.display = "block";
              } else {
              } 
            document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = "TYPE : " + (e.layer.feature.properties.Type).toUpperCase();
            document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = "<b>MY STORY : </b>" + e.layer.feature.properties.description;
            document.getElementById("photo").src = e.layer.feature.properties.image1;
            removeBanner();
    });
```